# Custom Function PHP

Tags: php, arrays

My code is below. I need to:

1. Create a function for `avg`.
2. Create a function for `bigger`.

This will help me repeat the process below for arrays `$n3` and `$n4`. I have tried to create a function for `avg` but it is just not right. Please, look below:

INPUT:

```
$n1 = array(4, 14, 8, 3, 24);
$n2 = array(3, 1, 4, 7, 5);
$n3 = array(0, 30, 7, 25, 17);
$n4 = array(6, 2, 5, 4, 3);

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++); {
    $average1[] = avg($n1[$i], $n2[$i]);
    $average2[] = avg($n3[$i], $n4[$i]);
    $bigger[] = bigger($average1[$i], $average2[$i]);
```

MY Output for function avg:

```
function avg($n1[$i], $n2[$i]) {
    $av = ($n1[i] + $n2[$i]) / 2;
    return $av;
}
echo $av;
```

Comment: I converted your options to numbered list so that it looks more attractive. I also indented your code so that it renders properly – please see [the editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting.

Answer (score 1):

To find max value

```
max($your_array);
```

To find avg

```
function average($your_array) {
 return array_sum($your_array) / count($your_array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like @user1844933 solution, but if for some weird or student purpose reason you need to create thes two functions byiterating the array, this can be the solution

```
<?php
$n1 = array(4, 14, 8, 3, 24);
$n2 = array(3, 1, 4, 7, 5);
$n3 = array(0, 30, 7, 25, 17);
$n4 = array(6, 2, 5, 4, 3);

function bigger($array) {
    $result = 0;
    foreach($array as $num) {
        if($num > $result) {
            $result = $num;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

function average($array) {
    $result = 0;
    foreach($array as $num) {
        $result += $num;
    }
    return $result / count($array);
}

echo "<h2>n1</h2>";
echo "Average: ".average($n1)."<br>";
echo "Bigger: ".bigger($n1)."<br>";

echo "<h2>n2</h2>";
echo "Average: ".average($n2)."<br>";
echo "Bigger: ".bigger($n2)."<br>";

echo "<h2>n3</h2>";
echo "Average: ".average($n3)."<br>";
echo "Bigger: ".bigger($n3)."<br>";

echo "<h2>n4</h2>";
echo "Average: ".average($n4)."<br>";
echo "Bigger: ".bigger($n4)."<br>";
```

---

**EDIT**
I am not checking if arrays has different amount of elements. I assumed both arrays always have the same amount of elements

```
<?php
$n1 = array(4, 14, 8, 3, 24);
$n2 = array(3, 1, 4, 7, 5);
$n3 = array(0, 30, 7, 25, 17);
$n4 = array(6, 2, 5, 4, 3);

function average($array1, $array2) {
    $result = 0;
    $result ="";
    for($i=0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
        $result .= "Average Between: ". $array1[$i] . " and " . $array2[$i] . " is " . ($array1[$i] + $array2[$i]) /
            2 . "<br>";
    }
    return $result;
}

echo "<h2>n1 & n2</h2>";
echo average($n1, $n2)."<br>";

echo "<h2>n3 & n4</h2>";
echo average($n3, $n4)."<br>";
```

**EDIT 2**

The SO user ask for this function in the comment.

```
function table($array) {
    $table = '<table style="border:1px solid #000;">';
    foreach($array as $row) {
        $table .= "<tr><td style='border:1px solid #000;'>$row</td></tr>";
    }
    $table .= '<table>';

    return $table;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right in assuming we need to create our own functions.I was trying to write my function avg() based on what you suggested, and came up with this .Like I mentioned, the expectation for the avg function is that you add the first item from the first array with the first item from the second array and divide it by two to get the average. The process needs to be repeated for each item in both the arrays.Please tell me how to rectify my code below?

Comment: function avg($n1,$n2){ $ result=0; foreach($n1 as $num1){ foreach($n2 as $num2){ $result=$num1+$num2 ; } return $result/count($n1,$n2) ; } } echo $result;

Comment: @newbie I am not sure exactly what you are asking for. However, I edited my answer. I hope I guessing correctly what you meant.

Comment: your code kind of works for me and i am trying to rectify a small error.thanks so much. I am also trying me to create a function to print a table(like a html table for the output of my array). Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: sure, what do you want to display in that table?

Comment: the averages of each item from n1 and n2 arrays get stored in a new array $average1. Similarly the averages of n3 and n4 get stored in another new array $average2. These 2 new arrays are compared and then the bigger of the values is stored in yet another new array $bigger. So now I need a table for printing each item for $average1, $average2 and $bigger (5 rows ).But this needs to be in a function that is created for the purpose

Comment: Try to use my `function table()` and change what it needs to achieve your goal.